# Using APScheduler with uWSGI and gevent

Tags: uwsgi, gevent, apscheduler

I am trying to run my Flask uWSGI application with APScheduler.
I was using it with the default in-memory jobstore without problems before, but now I need to persist some jobs that are scheduled far in the future in a PostgreSQL database, so it can live longer than the process.

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the jobstore, the uWSGI event loop doesn't start anymore.

The code I am running is:

```
def create_app(config: Config):
    scheduler = APScheduler()
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(config)

    from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
    ap_jobstore = SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
    scheduler.scheduler.add_jobstore(jobstore=ap_jobstore)

    scheduler.init_app(app)
    scheduler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_app(Config())
```

This is the full uWSGI output log:

```
flask_backend_container | *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.22 (64bit) on [Sat Jul 29 08:47:13 2023] ***
flask_backend_container | compiled with version: 10.2.1 20210110 on 29 July 2023 08:47:04
flask_backend_container | os: Linux-5.4.0-155-generic #172-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 7 16:10:02 UTC 2023
flask_backend_container | nodename: 04746b5c713a
flask_backend_container | machine: x86_64
flask_backend_container | clock source: unix
flask_backend_container | pcre jit disabled
flask_backend_container | detected number of CPU cores: 16
flask_backend_container | current working directory: /app
flask_backend_container | detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
flask_backend_container | uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
flask_backend_container | *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
flask_backend_container | your memory page size is 4096 bytes
flask_backend_container | detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
flask_backend_container | - async cores set to 1000 - fd table size: 1048576
flask_backend_container | lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
flask_backend_container | thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
flask_backend_container | uWSGI http bound on :5555 fd 4
flask_backend_container | uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:43057 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
flask_backend_container | uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
flask_backend_container | *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
flask_backend_container | Python version: 3.9.10 (main, Feb  8 2022, 05:06:38)  [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
flask_backend_container | Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55c674054aa0
flask_backend_container | uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
flask_backend_container | *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
flask_backend_container | python threads support enabled
flask_backend_container | your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
flask_backend_container | your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
flask_backend_container | mapped 21036928 bytes (20543 KB) for 1000 cores
flask_backend_container | *** Operational MODE: async ***
flask_backend_container | 'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
flask_backend_container | WARNING:root:/app/app
flask_backend_container | INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
flask_backend_container | 'FLASK_ENV' is deprecated and will not be used in Flask 2.3. Use 'FLASK_DEBUG' instead.
flask_backend_container | INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "cache_colors" to job store "default"
flask_backend_container | INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
flask_backend_container | WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 5 seconds on interpreter 0x55c674054aa0 pid: 1 (default app)
flask_backend_container | uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
flask_backend_container | *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
flask_backend_container | *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
flask_backend_container | spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
flask_backend_container | spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 28, cores: 1000)
flask_backend_container | spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 29)
```

After that, nothing happens: I cannot do any requests to Flask, as they fail.

When not initializing the PostgreSQL jobstore, the output log is the same *but one* additional line pops up at the end:

```
flask_backend_container | *** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55997f414e00] ***
```

This starts the backend successfully and I can do requests to it as used to.

I already read about uWSGI doing some stuff with the GIL, which APScheduler relies on. To fix this, I should add `--enable-threads` to the uWSGI command line, which I did. But it didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Is there anything I missed when setting the jobstores up?